# How to take last n elements from BroadcastProcessor, map them and return them via REST?

Tags: java, jax-rs, quarkus, mutiny

I want to create a method, either reactive or non-reactive, that is capable of taking *n* elements as a list from a `BroadcastProcessor`, maps them and returns them via HTTP.

I tried almost everything that came to my mind but I couldn't get around it. It either returned an empty object or an error.

Here's an example code of my idea:

```java
BroadcastProcessor<HashMap<String, Long>> timesSink = BroadcastProcessor.create();

// this works fine
public void addTimes(HashMap<String, Long> times) {
    this.timesSink.onNext(times);
}

// this works fine too
@GET
@Path("/stream")
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
public Multi<HashMap<String, Long>> getTimesStream() {
    return Multi.createBy().replaying().ofMulti(this.timesSink);
}

// THIS DOES NOT WORK AND IDK WHY
// n is amount of items I want to replay
@GET
@Path("/compact")
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
public Uni<HashMap<String, Long>> getTimesCompact() {
    return Multi.createBy().replaying().upTo(n).ofMulti(this.timesSink)
        .collect().asList()
        .map(this::toCompactTimes);
}

private HashMap<String, Long> toCompactTimes(List<HashMap<String, Long>> times) {
    // not relevant to the problem
    // it takes a list of HashMaps and calculates an average value
}
```

Here's a repo that reproduces the problem:
https://github.com/jpkmiller/mutiny-stackoverflow

Comment: Hello, would you have a minimal reproducer project?

Comment: Yes, I just created one: https://github.com/jpkmiller/mutiny-stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.collect().asList()` operator accumulates items into a list, but will only emit the list [once it has received a completion signal](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.smallrye.reactive/mutiny/latest/io/smallrye/mutiny/groups/MultiCollect.html) from its upstream/source.

Your code never sends a completion signal from `timesSkink`, hence it never gets a chance to emit the list.

The `/stream` endpoints shall "work" because RestEasy Reactive is sending batches of items while your `Uni`-returning endpoint is stuck waiting for the list to be sent.

Hope it helps and makes sense!

Comment: That helps alot! Thank you very much. If i call `timesSink.onComple()` wouldn't it then end the stream and the subscribtion? The problem is the stream is never ending. So at some point I want to call /compact or /avg (in repo) and get some of the streamed items without having to send `onComplete`.